# Argument of type "std::string (*)[10]" is incompatible with parameter of type "Movie *"

Tags: c++

I'm just a beginning coder and all.. I was trying to create a printed table using a static array of top 10 movies from rotten tomatoes along with their critic and audience rating.

I was given struct Movie and void PrintMovies. When I try to call PrintMovies however, the title array doesn't work. The error keeps saying that the argument is incompatible. I don't understand what that means nor understand how to fix it.

Also if you anyone knows how to finish displaying the table, can you help me? I made a for loop for the 2-D array, but I don't know how to continue after it.

```
   //--------------------------------Movie.h-------------------------------
         #ifndef _Movie_
        #define _Movie_
        #include <iostream>

        struct Movie
         {
            std::string title;
            int criticRating; // from 0 to 100
            int audienceRating; // from 0 to 100
        };

        #endif /*defined _Movie_*/
     //-----------------------------------Movie.cpp-----------------------------
        #include <iostream>
        #include <string>
        #include <algorithm>
        #include "Movie.h"
        #include <iomanip>
        using namespace std;

        void PrintMovies(Movie* movies, int numMovies);

        int main()
        {
            std::string titles[3][10] = { "Kung Fu Panda", "Hail, Caesar!", "Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens",
                            "The Revenant", "The Choice","Pride and Prejudice and Zombies","The Finest Hours",
                            "Ride Along 2", "The Boy","Dirty Grandpa" };
            PrintMovies(titles, 10);
            return 0;
        }

        void PrintMovies(Movie* movies, int numMovies)
        {
            cout << "Movies\n";
            cout << "Critic\t" << "Audience\t" << "Title\n";
            for (int row = 0; row < 3; ++row)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: The function expects an array of `Movie` values.  You have passed an array of `std::string` values.  This is a fundamental flaw in your program, but I cannot provide this as an answer, because it's not clear how you actually want the program to behave.

Comment: am, ok..where to start: 1.- Why not make a hole class of it. 2.- from PrintMovies prototye, you can't cast from std::string to Movie*.

Comment: @paddy Actually, they have passed a pointer to an array of`std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::string titles[3][10] = {...}
```

generates a two-dimensional array of strings, while your function expects to get a pointer to a `Movie` object. Those are different types and the compiler is not able to figure out how to convert one into the other.

One option is to use a vector like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> titles = {...};
std::vector<Movie> movies;
for(std::string title : titles)
    movies.push_back({title,0,0}); //here the conversion happens:
                                 // we use a string (title) and two ints to generate a movie
```

and then change the signatur of your function to

```
void PrintMovies(std::vector<Movie>& movies);
```

Comment: then what happens to PrintMovies(...) in main? What do I put in the parentheses? I never used vectors before.. :/

Comment: Oh... Is "titles" in the parentheses then changed to "movies"?

Comment: In the parantheses you add the comma-seperated list of strings just as you did with your string-array. You then get a vector of strings instead of an array of strings, still named "titles". The for-loop converts one title after another to a movie and adds it to a vector of movies called "movies". You call the function then as `PrintMovies(movies);` and get the number of movies as `movies.size()`. [This reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The line of code

```
    std::string titles[3][10] = { "Kung Fu Panda", "Hail, Caesar!", "Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens",
                    "The Revenant", "The Choice","Pride and Prejudice and Zombies","The Finest Hours",
                    "Ride Along 2", "The Boy","Dirty Grandpa" };
```

erroneously tries to create a 3 x 10 array of movie titles, but you only pass it 10 movie titles. It's completely unclear what you were trying to do here. But I suspect what you wanted was:

```
    std::string titles[10] = { "Kung Fu Panda", "Hail, Caesar!", "Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens",
                    "The Revenant", "The Choice","Pride and Prejudice and Zombies","The Finest Hours",
                    "Ride Along 2", "The Boy","Dirty Grandpa" };
```

Now you have the names of the movies, but they aren't `Movie`s yet, they are `std::string`s. So you can't just pass them to your `PrintMovies` function. You'll need to create and populate an array of `Movie`s

Here is a cleaned-up "[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)" of your code to help you get started.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

struct Movie
{
    std::string title;
    int criticRating; // from 0 to 100
    int audienceRating; // from 0 to 100
};

void PrintMovies(Movie* movies, int numMovies)
{
    std::cout << "Movies\n";
    std::cout << "Critic\t" << "Audience\t" << "Title\n";
    for (int row = 0; row < 3; ++row)
    {
        ///TODO: Rethink this, you have to print numMovies movies.
    }
}

int main()
{
    constexpr auto NumMovies = 10;
    // or static const size_t NumMovies = 10;

    std::string titles[NumMovies] = { "Kung Fu Panda", "Hail, Caesar!", "Star Wars: Episode VII - The Force Awakens",
                    "The Revenant", "The Choice","Pride and Prejudice and Zombies","The Finest Hours",
                    "Ride Along 2", "The Boy","Dirty Grandpa" };          
    ///TODO: array of critic ratings
    ///TODO: array of audience ratings.

    ///TODO: Create and populate array of Movies called "movies".
    Movie movies[NumMovies];  // Something like this
    for (auto i = 0; i < NumMovies; ++i)
    {
        movies[i].title = titles[i];
        // ...
    }

    PrintMovies(movies, NumMovies);
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/31z0u4

Notes:

. Instead of writing '10' everywhere, I created a constant alias for it -- NumItems. Within the scope it is declared in, i.e. main, you can use "NumItems" instead of the current number of movies. It helps keep things consistent.

. In the for loop I used the C++11 keyword "auto" to care about what type of value my invariant is,

. I've not solved a number of other problems with your implementation, since this seems to be an early learning phase of a C++ book/course.